# I'm getting an error I can't figure out trying to run a OOP PHP query

Tags: php, function, class, oop, public

This is my first time with OOP PHP and I am trying to build a Login - Register system. I found a tutorial online which seemed have what i needed. I am not far into the tutorial but I have found an error and I can’t find a solution. I have tried different way to run the query from the index page but none work

The DB.php

```
<?php
class DB {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_PDO, 
    $_query, 
    $_error = false, 
    $_results, 
    $_count = 0;

    private function __construct() {
        try {
            $this-> pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'),  Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
            echo 'Connected';
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance(){
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
        $this->_error = false;
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            echo 'Query Success';
          
                }
            }
}
```

The init.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'root',
        'db' => ‘my_db’
    ),
    'remember' => array(
        'cookie_name' => 'hash',
        'cookie_expiry' => 2628288
    ),
    'session' => array(
        'session_user' => 'user'
    )
);

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
});

require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
```

The sanitize.php

```
<?php 
function escape($string){
    return htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

//In the tutorial, the following is all that is required to get Success.
```

The index. php

```
<?php 
require_once 'core/init.php';

DB::getInstance()->query('SELECT username FROM users');

//echo ' from index page';

?>
```

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `joined` datetime NOT NULL,
  `group` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Sorry if I have not posted this question correctly.

Comment: **I'm getting an error** - what error did you get ?

Comment: The `query()` method only prepares the query, it never executes it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a good tutorial. `htmlentities()` has nothing to do with sanitizing data; it's used when displaying data on a web page to prevent XSS. And if you use prepared queries with parameters, you don't need to sanitize the data.

Comment: I am getting 500 (Internal Server Error). Usually when I get this error I look to see if i have an error in the php.

Comment: Sorry Barmar. There is an execute part to the script which was not included. But following the tutorial, the instructor show that he can run the query and get a success before using the rest of the script. The problem I find with some online tutorials is I have to do them bit by bit. If I go too far in and get an error I. don't have enough experience to fix it.

Comment: It is rather problematic, that people new to programming and web development always seem to jump on the topic of a login system as one of the very first things. This is one of those that have the highest potential for really bad mistakes, that could actually have _severe_ consequences, should such a system every get actually put to use in a "live" scenario. People should really learn the basics on less crucial topics first, IMHO.